# Hadoop Scoobi : instantiate a DList from XML

Tags: xml, scala, hadoop, scoobi

I am fairly new to Scala, Hadoop & Scoobi.

We have some hadoop jobs where we process `CSV` files and do the Scoobi routines with

```
  // Parse the input file
  val lines = fromTextFile(input)

  // Iterate on every element to generate the keys, and then aggregate it
  val counts = lines.mapFlatten( ...
```

**1. I have the impression that I can't do it for XML files. Is that so? or can i process XML with Scoobi?**

**2. I think I can parse and flatten the XML nodes to a lines with scala native xml. But then how do I create a [Scoobi DList](http://nicta.github.io/scoobi/guide/com.nicta.scoobi.guide.DistributedLists.html).**

*(why? because I will need to join it with another one coming from a CSV file)*

***Note :*** My xml consists of nodes like the following :

```
 <add>
    <AdCampaign class="BCSAdCampaign">
        <Subscriber>TVC</Subscriber>
        <CampaignName>3402376</CampaignName>
        <CampaignId>1NTGXNAY</CampaignId>
        <AccountManager/>
        <FromDate>20130212</FromDate>
        <ToDate>20140207</ToDate>
        <ReportingInd>N</ReportingInd>
        <CampaignAdmin>NAWASTHI MCG-TVC</CampaignAdmin>
        <SalesChannel>TC8</SalesChannel>
        <Email/>
        <Advertiser>MU0</Advertiser>
        <Date>20150609</Date>
    </AdCampaign>
</add>
```